# Permission denied error, Failed to write pid file while docker compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permissions, mnesia

```
error:
ampq_1  | Failed to write pid file: /mnesia/rabbit@50751ab1f5b1.pid
ampq_1  | /opt/rabbitmq/sbin/rabbitmq-server: line 51: can't create /mnesia/rabbit@50751ab1f5b1.pid: Permission denied
```

while running the services of docker

yml file:

```yaml
ampq:
    networks:
      - ampq_gmp

    volumes:
      - /media/data/ampq/gmpqueue:/mnesia

    user: ${HOST_DOCKER_UID}

    environment:
      RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE: /mnesia
```

DockerFile:

FROM rabbitmq:3-management-alpine

COPY ./configs/ampq /devhost

I used this command: docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build ampq

please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Are you actually getting that error running `docker build`?  The YAML fragment you attached isn't enough to launch a container (it doesn't have `image:` or `build:`); can you edit the question to include a [mcve], including the Dockerfile if it is a build-time problem?

Answer (score 1):

These are linux based containers as i'm using windows machine because of this i'm getting permission denied issue, I cannot run this service, this containers will run only in linux distribution